# How to mount an external Hard Drive connected to a netgear router?

Tags: networking, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a Laptop running Ubuntu. The external Hard Drive is attached to the netgear router. Both are wire connected.  The external Hard Drive shows under the network section in files. but when I try to get plex to find it the external Hard Drive doesn't show up.

I tried the instructions for Mounting NTFS Drives on 
Linux https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux
this gives an error that the devise is in use or already mounted. So I unmounted it and tried again and received the same error.

Perhaps using this process I am reading the NTFS drive of my laptop? I cannot tell.

I tried adding this entry to `/etc/fstab`

```
//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/mybook/ /media/public ntfs-3g permissions,auto 0 0
```

got an error:

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/mybook/': No such file or directory
```

I don't have much experience with Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Chris

Comment: ntfs-3g is probably a wrong file system for a network share, try `cifs` instead.

Comment: As @mikewhatever said. Don't try to mount it wirh ntfs, even though your hard disk is formatted like this. Drives connected over network need to be mount with a networking protocol like smb. In that case you need to mount it with the cifs driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this package:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Create a mount-point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/my_supercool_hdd
```

Add this entry to your **/etc/fstab** :

```
//192.168.178.100/my_shared_folder /media/my_supercool_hdd cifs auto  0 0
```

The entry above means:

```
//<Server>/<Share> <Mountpoint> cifs <mounting-options>  0  0
```

You can use *auto* as option to mount your share while booting or *noauto* to prepare it for later.

If your share is password protected your entry would look like this:

```
//192.168.1.100/my_shared_folder /media/my_supercool_hdd cifs user=john,passwd=supersecretpassword auto 0 0
```

Comment: lbreuer, I used cifs as you and Mike suggested but I get a request for a password:  Password for root@//192.168.1.1/My_Book: 

The external hard drive has no password, its open to all on the wired network. 
sounds like I am close, this is the entry I used

Comment: i used  //192.168.1.1/My_Book /media/my_super_hdd cifs auto  0 0 
tried to use the Netgear password but got error: mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
I know its not down, I can see it on the windows computer.

Comment: @Chris98275 if you have no password, you need the "guest" option. Recently, you also need the "sec=ntlm" option. Here is my `etc/fstab` line:
`//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/ /data cifs guest,sec=ntlm 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the drive is properly unmounted, can you find the output of the command!

`lsof -p <mount_path_HD>`

Also, once that is umounted,

Try to see if there is an entry in the disk list with!

`sudo fdisk -l`

Presuming the external disk as ``172.16.0.172:/mnt/netgear` , mount as follows!

Then try mounting!

`sudo mount -t nfs /mnt/netgear /media`

before mounting, make sure you have created a folder named `media`

Then make an entry in fstab as follows!

`172.16.0.172:/mnt/netgear /media nfs defaults 1 2`

HTH!